# How can I render a template in Go without any variables?

Tags: go

I've loaded a template file into memory with the following code:

```
t := template.New("master")
tpl, err := t.ParseFiles("templates/index.html")
```

Now I want to draw that template into a string, so my `index.html` is pretty empty:

```
{{define "master"}}
Hello World
{{end}}
```

I'm just starting out, so I don't have any data yet. Is there a way I can convert the `Template` object into a string without data?

Answer (score 4):

If your template doesn't (yet) use any variables, you can just pass *any* value as data to render the template. So, to render the template to stdout, you could for example use:

```
tpl.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
```

If you really want to render the template to a string, you can use a [`bytes.Buffer`](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) as an intermediary:

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
tpl.Execute(&buf, nil)
str := buf.String()
```

Answer (score -1):

This is impossible in Go, by design - if you don't have data, the Template package is unnecessary overhead.

If you have no data, just read the file using the `io` package, instead of using templates.